# How could i search between two string type date

Tags: sql-server, date, string

Consider these two tables. I use persian dates, so I have to declare `startdate` and `enddate` as a string(`nvarchar(10)`).

crt table:

```
id title startdate enddate
--------------------------
1  xyz   1395/01/01  1395/12/29
2  xyy   1394/12/01  1395/05/05
3  cvb   1392/02/03  1394/02/03
```

season table:

```
id title startdate enddate
--------------------------
1  spring95 1395/01/01  1395/03/31
```

I want to write a query that gives me crt records that are valid in a season. IE `crt.startdate<=season.startdate and crt.enddate>=season.enddate`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is this question of the performance or solution to accomplish that?

Comment: it is a question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you encounter performance problems you could store the dates as integers instead of varchar. 1397-12-09 becomes 13971209, all the numbers remain in sequence so you can still carry out BETWEEN queries. Then convert your results to date format at the final point of presentation.

Comment: If Sedighe can store the dates as integers instead of varchar why not just save it as datetime in first place. Most probability there must be some strong limitation to opt the varchar type column.

Comment: The Datetime datatype only goes back to 1753. This is because when countries converted to the Gregorian calendar they did all kinds of crazy things like jumping from 3rd of September to 17th of September overnight.

Comment: I believe datetime2 data type can accommodate the dates prior to 1753.

Comment: But valid point on 3rd Sep to 17th Sep jump. :)

Comment: @pacreely ,@SwapnilBhate.. i have to show the table so i could not use integer to save date.however i think it's good idea to save both...when i want to use query i use integer an d when i want to show i use string :)

Comment: Datetime2 requires at least 6 bytes of storage, Integer requires 4. Unless you are interested in storing the time-of-day on 1397-12-09 then Integer will provide improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Below query can help you. You can make use of convert function.

SELECT convert(datetime2, '1395/01/01', 111) will return the 1395-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 in datatime2 format. Why to use datetime2, because the data you have provided can be out of bounds for the usual datetime format. More info can be found in the this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server).

```
SELECT *
FROM crt AS C
    INNER JOIN season AS S
    ON C.id = S.id -- Or any required join condition
WHERE convert(datetime2, c.startdate, 111) <= convert(datetime2, s.startdate, 111)
    AND convert(datetime2, c.enddate, 111) >= convert(datetime2, s.enddate, 111)
```

Comment: i use the query and i have this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: when i use datetime2 datatype and i declare columns i want to put data in it i get this error"unable to read data"

Comment: @Sedighe: Must be the database version issue. It worked on my SQL 2012 server. But anyhow you should opt for the solution proposed by pacreely. That's a very nice and simple solution for your problem rather that converting it to datetime2 before comparison.